# Read text files and separate to lines by character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have text file with this example content:

```
12/13/18, 14:06 - her:IMG-20181213-WA0005.jpg (file attached)12/13/18, 14:06 - her:PTT-20181213-WA0006.opus (file attached)12/13/18, 14:07 - kristal: its not in the right quality?12/13/18, 14:14 - her:bla bla bla bla12/13/18, 14:43 - kristal: ok for this size12/13/18, 14:43 - kristal: somthing somthing
12/13/18, 14:43 - kristal: rect12/13/18, 14:43 - Enav Sharon-kristal: need square12/13/18, 14:48 - her:sending files12/13/18, 14:49 - Enav Sharon-kristal: ok then
```

How do I make a code that reads all the text and divide it to rows (when you see 12 break the line) and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want a `new line` before every `12`?

I see that it comes from a *date*, but if you look at:

```
12/13/18, 14:06 - her:IMG-20181213-WA0005.jpg
```

there is a `12` in the text where you **might not want a new line**.

The solution might be robust if you break before a **date**:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file: # the file you want to read
    with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as new_file: # the file you want to save
        for line in file.readlines():

            new_line = re.sub('(\d+/\d+/\d+)', '\n\g<1>', line).strip()) # find all dates

            new_file.write('{}\n'.format(new_line)) # save to new file
```

Comment: @graphicsgraphics glad to help :) If you feel like your question has been answered, feel free to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the string replace() method to do this:

```
your_long_string.replace('12', '\n12')
```

You can be more specific; maybe you're worried some of the messages contain '12' outside the date:

```
your_long_string.replace('12/', '\n12/')
```

If you need to be even more robust, you need to learn to use regular expressions (that could get a bit complicated; [have a look](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto)).

You can split this into an array of lines:

```
your_long_string.replace('12/', '\n12/').splitlines()
```

You can loop through each line like this:

```
for line in your_long_string.replace('12/', '\n12/').splitlines():
    # do whatever
    print(line)
```

Or you can just save it back to a text file:

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
long_string = file.read()
file.close()
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(long_string.replace('12/', '\n12/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the preferred output is a list of rows, try *split()*

```
rows = text.split("12")
```

And for joining these rows, use *join()*

```
linebreaked_text = "/n12".join(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple :D

If you want result to be list,

```
data = string.split(“12”)
```

or if you want result to be string divided by line,

```
data = “\n”.join(string.split(“12”))
```

Python has many good methods